# Two html <option> output from php while loop not works

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want two `<option>` output form database by while loop and also need to receive it form `$_POST['']` function but i am getting only one `<option>` output. double `<option>` not appears form these codes. what wrong i am doing here?

```
$q6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
echo '<form action="" method="post">'.'Need To Change <select name="tobechanged">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q6)) {
    $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$menu_name.'">'.$menu_name.'</option>';

}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q6)) {
    $menu_name2 = $row['menu_name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$menu_name2.'">'.$menu_name2.'</option>';

}

echo '</select><br>
  <input type="submit" name="pchange_submit" value="Change it">
</form>';

if (isset($_POST['pchange_submit'])) {
    echo $_POST['tobechanged'];
}
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch` consumes rows, so your first loops uses up all the rows in the result set, then your second loop never kicks in because the fetch call returns boolean false (no more records). Why would you want to do this anyways? even if you did rewind the query, you'd just be outputting duplicate options, which is rather pointless.

Comment: then whats the solution to get double return?

Comment: run one loop, build a string of your options, then output the string twice. or rewind the query result.

Comment: Here you wanna 2 select output or 1 Select with to option statemant?

Comment: actually i want to use it for navigation menu parent change. so i need 2 option there user will select one to assign as parent nav for another

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $q6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
echo '<form action="" method="post">'.'Need To Change <select name="tobechanged">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q6)) {
    $menu_name = $row['menu_name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$menu_name.'">'.$menu_name.'</option>';

}

echo '</select><br>
  <input type="submit" name="pchange_submit" value="Change it">
</form>';

if (isset($_POST['pchange_submit'])) {
    echo $_POST['tobechanged'];
}
```